# Algorithm to run through all combinations of integer array

Tags: java, c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting

What is the most effective algorithm to run through all of the different permutations of an integer array? Specifically, I have an array which can hold 4 elements of size uint32_t in C++ terms, but I need to implement it in Java, so I guess I will need to cap it at 4,294,967,295 using a long. So an example output would be something like this:

```
[1,1,1,1]
[2,1,1,1]
[3,1,1,1]
[4,1,1,1]
[1,2,1,1]
[1,3,1,1]
[1,4,1,1]
[1,1,2,1]
[1,1,3,1]
[1,1,4,1]
...
[4,294,967,295, 4,294,967,295, 4,294,967,295, 4,294,967,295]
```

It doesn't need to go through it in that order. As long as it tries all combinations.

Thanks!

Comment: Those are neither permutations nor combinations, at least in the technical sense.

Comment: Also, that would be `10^38` different possibilities.

Comment: This is very probably a XY problem... What is the real problem you are trying to solve? Because it will take a VERY long time just with `int`, I can't even begin to imagine how long it would take with `long`...

Comment: Why would you print it , you are not doing anything algorithmic-ally, any 4 random numbers from 1 to 4,294,967,295 is one of your permutation.

Answer (score 3):

I hope you are patient, because there are quite a few possible combinations.

You don't allow 0, so the total is slightly less than 2<sup>128</sup> possible combinations. There are only 4,294,967,295<sup>4</sup> of them, or 340,282,366,604,025,813,516,997,721,482,669,850,625.

So if you could process a thousand million of those per second, then it would only take 10,790,283,060,756,779,982,147 years to do the computation, give or take the lifetime of a universe.

It's possible that you will need a better strategy for finding the correct solution than a brute force enumeration of all possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Simply with several loops:

```
for (int a = 0; a != max_int; ++a) {
    for (int b = 0; b != max_int; ++b) {
        for (int c = 0; c != max_int; ++c) {
            for (int d = 0; d != max_int; ++d) {
                std::cout << a << b << c << d << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are too many possibilites, this will never finish. Note that the OP wants to handle `long` also, not just `int`...

Comment: @Tunaki, the problem I'm trying to solve is that one of those combinations is the correct answer, but I don't know which. Unfortunately, I only choose long because there's no concept of uint in Java :(

Comment: That is _exactly_ what I feared. And, well, you're doing it wrong! You simply can't generate all the possibilities... There are too many. The problem you are trying to solve must be tackled from a different angle; brute force is not the only solution.

Comment: How would you tackle it if you don't know what the value is ?